# Is this really a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my book, I have a question saying

"Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ with the following operation
$$x\times y=x+y-3xy$$
is an (abelian) group."

Just like this. I know that that it's identity is zero. My point is that in order to compute the inverse $y$ of $x$, I wrote

$$x\times y =0 \Rightarrow x+y-3xy=0 \Rightarrow e=\frac{-x}{1-3x}.$$

Should my book have considered $\mathbb{R}-\{1/3\}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you are right. You can see that $1/3\times y = 1/3$ for every $y$, i.e. $1/3$ is an absorbing element. This cannot happen in a group.

Comment: Again, what book are you referring to? Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: What's more, $\mathbb R\setminus\{1/3\}$ is indeed a group